# what is the right syntax for a json file?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, decodable

I wish to populate various collection views and table views with data from a json file. However I do not know how to write that JSON file.

here is the data I wish to populate:

- 2 sectors : "data" and "developers"
- each sector contains a number of items:

for "data" :

- "Data Scientist",
- "Business Intelligence Analyst (BIA)",
- "Database Developer",
- "Database Administrator",
- "Data Engineer",
- "Data Analytics Manager",
- "Data Security Administrator"

for "developer":

- "APL",
- "BASIC",
- "Eiffel",
- "Frink",
- "Lisp",
- "Pascal",
- "Python",
- "Ruby",
- "S-Lang"

How would I need to organize the data so I can later retrieve them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *translate* the JSON to sections I'd recommend an array

```
[
    {"title":"data",
     "items":["Data Scientist","Business Intelligence Analyst (BIA)","Database Developer","Database Administrator","Data Engineer","Data Analytics Manager","Data Security Administrator"]
    },
    {"title":"developer",
     "items":["APL","BASIC","Eiffel","Frink","Lisp","Pascal","Python","Ruby","S-Lang"]
    }
]
```

and decode it to

```
struct Section : Decodable {
   let title : String
   let items : [String]
}
```

It's the most suitable structure for a table/collection view data source

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a pretty staight-forward format - strings are denoted by double-quotes, arrays are denoted by square brackets and dictionaries are dentoed by curly barces:

```
{
    "data" : [
        "Data Scientist",
        "Business Intelligence Analyst (BIA)",
        "Database Developer",
        "Database Administrator",
        "Data Engineer",
        "Data Analytics Manager",
        "Data Security Administrator"
    ],
    "developer": [
        "APL",
        "BASIC",
        "Eiffel",
        "Frink",
        "Lisp",
        "Pascal",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "S-Lang"
    ]
}
```